# How to XOR the pixels values of two bitmaps together?

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have some bitmap A which I modify to produce bitmap B. I want to efficiently produce a bitmap D by XORing the pixels values of A and B together such that D XOR A produces bitmap B and D XOR B produces bitmap A. I want to store the differences between the bitmaps so I can reverse changes that I've made.

So far I've tried:

1. Drawing A onto B with a paint object that I've called .setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.XOR)) on. This works when the alpha of A and B is 255 everywhere but anything below produces undesirable results. If I XOR A onto A, for example, I'd expect the result to be a blank image. With this xfer mode, most of A will disappear but the parts without full alpha will remain.
2. Drawing A onto B with a paint object that I've called .setXfermode(new PixelXorXfermode(0)) on. This xfer mode destroys alpha values, which isn't what I want. I'm also not sure what useful things I can set the constructor value to.

What can I do? I need something that will treat the pixel values as plain values and not treat the alpha values as a special case. I need this to be fairly fast (like the above paint types are) and using something like setpixel/getpixel or doing the calculations myself in a byte[] will  be far too slow.

Edit: Can anyone help with this? Even knowing that most people don't believe there is an API call that will do this for me will help. I'm almost desperate enough to switch to OpenGL rendering as this has an XOR rendering mode (which I hope doesn't have the same issue above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it at all possible to try XORing the bitmaps' byte arrays before drawing?  That would provide no special handling to alphas, and might in theory work if the bitmaps are identically sized.  It may not be fast, of course...

Or maybe you can use one of the above methods, but somehow manipulate the alpha values from the byte arrays and handle them separately?

Comment: XORing two 400x800 bitmaps on a Droid (without a JIT) takes about 0.3s which is way too slow. I'm probably going to have to do this using the NDK.

Answer (score 0):

as an alternative, consider copying the original image into a buffer.  to undo you just copy the saved image over the changed image. it shouldn't take any more memory and avoids the XOR issue.

Comment: The problem with this is you don't have enough information to redo the operation (without having to compute the changes again which can be slow) and the XORed image is much easier to compress in many situations.